# How to deal with Promise when function return value after some time

Tags: javascript, node.js

set timeout taking time to call the function but code need to wait until return has not return

```js
var test = new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
   resolve(2);
}) 
test.then(r).then(s).then(t).then((tt)=>{
  console.log(tt);
});
function r(r){  
  setTimeout(()=>{
    r=r+1;
    return(r);
  },2000)
}

function s(r){
  r=r+1;
  return(r);
}
function t(r){
  r=r+1;
  return(r);
}
```

Comment: Please clearly ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

You are not awaiting setTimeOut function to finish

```js
var test = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    return resolve(2);
})
test.then(r).then(s).then(t).then((tt) => {
    console.log(tt);
});

function r(r) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            r = r + 1;
            return resolve(r);
        }, 2000)
    })
}

function s(r) {
    r = r + 1;
    return r;
}

function t(r) {
    r = r + 1;
    return r;
}
```